# Check if array of integer 0, 1 and -1 symbols contains a sequence of 1 null

Tags: java, regex

So I got an integer array of 48 elements and I want to check if the array contains a sequence of 1 individual 0.

This array contains such a sequence: 0111101100011

This array doesn't: 0011110001111

How can I check this in a regular expression in Java?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Please provide more details. Do you want to detect if it contains lone zeroes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like: `[^0](0)[^0]`, or `^|[^0](0)[^0]|$` to take the edges in account (thanks Sam I am). Note that this will match up to 3 characters, you need to get the position of group 1 of the match to find the position of the actual 0 digit.

Answer (score 3):

the regex" `"[^0]0[^0]"` will match one without the solitary `0` at the beginning or the end

you migh also want to check it against  `"^0[^0]"`  and  `"[^0]0$"` for the edge cases

Comment: @owlstead I was taking my time to try to think of a way to take the edge cases of '01110', but when you see that orange box up there saying that someone has already answered, you feel a little bit rushed